# Gitignore ignore generate file with the same name

Tags: git, gitignore

Hi I'm using JR programming language in class to work with thread, mutex, etc. The language is pretty much not documented. I try to create a github repo for the homework and while this is not a real problem, we need to generate file in order to use monitor. So our code is in the file name whateverMonitor.m and we use a tool m2jr like that :

```
m2jr -sw whateverMonitor.m
```

This will generate whateverMonitor.jr that is generated code but as the monitor is not support in JR, it's faking monitor and translate every line that we edit in the *.m to is JR counterpart. So is there a way to tell in the .gitignore file that if there is this regex file : **([a-zA-Z]+).m** and find this file **{0}.jr** file, ignore **{0}.jr**? (only the JR counterpart as it will create multiple edit every change we do in the .m file)

Comment: No, there is no such a way. `.gitignore` is a simple list of shell patterns, no conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to make sure to use your generate command in a dedicated folder (for instance "`generated`")

```
cd your/repo
mkdir generated
cd generated
m2jr -sw ../whateverMonitor.m
```

That way, any jr file generated there can be ignore: you can ignore the all "generated" folder with `your/repo/.gitignore` including that one line:

```
 generated/
```